# German term for 'toe clamp'?

Tags: technical-terminology

There's a thing called a 'toe clamp' (sample image here: https://catalog.monroeengineering.com/Asset/14101p.jpg) that is used to hold a workpiece on a machine table. It's quite similar to what's known in German as a 'Spannpratze' but instead of clamping something down to the machine table, it clamps it on the side.
Is there an equivalent term in German?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [machinist's catalogue](https://www.kippwerk.de/de/de/Produkte/Spanntechnik/Werkst%C3%BCck-Spanntechnik/Spannelemente/K0853-2-Tiefspanner-verstellbar-abgesetzt.html) lists your item as

> Tiefspanner

The clamping movement is, actually, inward *and* down.

The term *Spannpratze* is actually not proper ("official") terminology in German as defined by DIN and machinist's textbooks - That thing is a *Spanneisen*.

Comment: I appreciate your resourcefulnes including areas such as machining tools. I also tried to find catalogues listing these clamps but I did not find one. - I would, however, be cautious with the word "official" in this context. There is, of course, terminology that is recognized by practitioners (here: machinists) and is used in textbooks etc. in the industry. But I would not call this "official", rather "common practice in the industry", or if you like, an *industry standard* (the latter not in the technical sense, of course).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Machinist's language is special: Everyone who knows how to use it, will call the thing that's "officially" (yes, by textbooks and DIN, no caution needed) called a "Rollgabelschlüssel" an "Engländer", a "Gliedermassstab" a "Meterstab", a "Schraubendreher" a "Schraubenzieher", and a "Winkelschleifer" a "Flex".

Comment: Most people here would call a "Meterstab" a "Zollstock". But terms like "Engländer", "Flex", etc. are used here too, by all kinds of "Handwerker" and hobbyists. But these days, even "Handwerker" say "Schraubendreher". Note that a "Rollgabelschlüssel" is not exactly the same as an "Engländer", although both terms are used for both kinds of tool.

Comment: @tofro and that’s probably the source of quite a few misunderstandings. I’m neither a machinist nor a very handy person, but according to Wikipedia, an *Engländer* is not actually a *Rollgabelschlüssel*, but a *Universalschlüssel* oder *Universalschraubenschlüssel* ;-)